# What can I (inexpensively) use to create property design?

Tags: web-apps, osx, 3d, landscape

I would like to find software that allows me to create a crude model of potential property design that includes the views from the property, which is located in a valley and has mountain views in most directions.

I know I *can* do this with Sketchup Pro, but this is a personal, not a professional project, and I don't need all of the features Pro offers, especially at $350, but the free version doesn't seem to import terrain nor satellite image data, just the street map. I don't mind paying for a product, but not for one designed for professional architects.

I don't need this to be super high resolution. The goal is to give me a somewhat realistic view of the location after I add in features such as buildings, landscaping, etc.

I'm open to solutions that run on either macOS or the web.